# Ruby on rails helper method instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, methods

I am following along with Michael Hartl's rails tutorial. I am confused with a portion of the sessions helper module.

In the following code can someone please clarify if the  `current_user` in the `logged_in?` method refers to the actual method `current_user` and is read as the user is only logged_in? if the method `current_user` dies not return nil?

OR

Is the `current_user` referring to the instance variable `@current_user`  inside of the `current_user` method

Any clarification is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

```rb
module SessionsHelper
  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]) 
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end 
end
```

Comment: The former is correct. `logged_in?`  means: The return value from the `current_user` method is not (`!`) `nil?`.

Comment: thank you for the clarification that really helps me understand what is going on. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every module that you put in the `app/helpers` directory is included into your controllers. When you include a module you add it to the ancestors chain of the class so it behaves as if the method was defined in the class itself.

So to explain the `current_user` method line by line it checks if the session has the key `:user_id` and then assigns the instance variable `@current_user` to the controller if its not already set. This is known as a memoizing getter method - and avoids firing a database query to fetch the user every time its called.

In `logged_id?` you're using that getter method:

```
# Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
def logged_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

It could actually be written as `!@current_user.nil?`. But there is a big caveat - in Ruby you can reference instance variables that are not set without error. So if you made a typo and wrote`!@curent_user.nil?` it would just fail unexpectedly as its always nil.

When creating an authentication system there should also only be one method that knows how to fetch the user, and all other code should go through that system so that the implementation details don't leak out all over the place.

Comment: Thank you for the very  thorough  and detailed explanation. Very very helpful. Much Appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Technically speaking `current_user.nil?` is `session[:user_id]` is falsey or `@current_user.nil?` rather than strictly `@current_user.nil?` because theoretically `@current_user.nil? #=> false` but `session[:user_id] #=> nil` and thus `current_user.nil? != @current_user.nil?`

Comment: @engineersmnky yes - you're correct. I forgot about the return value of the `if` expression.